# delete lines of a file from a file

Tags: sed

I have about 14k lines to delete from a file. They are in another file:

```
$ cat delete.lineno.txt
12d
23d
24d
78d
...
..

etc.
```

I need to delete lines 12, 23,24,78 etc from a file say my.file.txt.
How can I implement this using `sed`?

Comment: `sed -f delete.lineno.txt < file.in > file.out`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780203/deleting-lines-from-one-file-which-are-in-another-file

Comment: Some strange answers at the above link :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-f` option to make `sed` read command from file:

```
sed -f delete.lineno.txt < my.file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @cuonglm and Stephane Chazelas. Thats exactly what I am looking for. How should I create my delete.lineno.txt ? separated by space, comma, or each delete lien number as a newline ? Thanks !!

Comment: @aroraa: In `sed -f script`, `script` contains `sed` command to be applied. Your `delete.lineno.tx` is legal and you can use it safely.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I just tried it with a test file and it works!

Comment: @aroraa Maybe accept cuonglm's solution as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sed` - it's not the tool for this job.  Use `ex`, a superset of `ed`.

```
tac delete.lineno.txt > cmds
echo 'w!' >> cmds
echo 'q!' >> cmds
ex -s file < cmds
```

Delete from the back of the file to avoid messing up the line numbering while you delete.

Comment: Will it still mess up with sed -f option ?

Comment: @aroraa - I don't think so. `sed` has a different idea of how lines are numbered, because it never "backs up", and it has a sequence of input lines. The `sed -f` solution is probably the best - less work than mine.